# Grabbing the Value of Path in Firebase With Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to grab the value of a path in Firebase. Say I do

```
firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  var displayName = 
    firebase.database()
    .ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/name/')
    .once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val());

    store.dispatch('checkUser', {
        user
        displayName
    });
});
```

In my console I get a promise as the value of my users `displayName`, inside of that I see the correct value, but how do I get to it? It throws me an error when I try and set displayName to `snapshot.val()` in the callback.

[image]

[image]

Why can't I do this? Seems like in the documentation it's possible.

[image]

Comment: The reason it's not available is because you're calling `store.dispatch` synchronously,. and it's firing before `snapshot.val()` is available. You were correct to try and put the `dispatch` into the last `Promise`'s callback. You were, however, *incorrect* to not include the `error` text in your question, as that's likely the root of the problem.

Comment: @Brandon I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: The Firebase auth subsystem will store the display name, username, imageUrl, all that...  You can't view it via their GUI though.  All you need to do is ask for the currentUser property. See https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth

Comment: @RonRoyston I'm using email and password sign up though so I don't get a displayName property automatically when a user creates an account I don't believe.

Comment: @staxwell True, right.  It's been a while since I played with it but as I remember you can in fact set displayName directly into the Firebase auth subsystem.  You do have to capture it though.  I hope I'm making sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because the syntax is incorrect; it would need to be enclosed in a block:

```
.once('value').then(snapshot => { const displayName = snapshot.val(); });
```

However, that won't solve the problem. You need to move the `dispatch` call into the callback - where the snapshot has been resolved:

```
firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  firebase.database()
    .ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/name/')
    .once('value').then(snapshot => store.dispatch('checkUser', {
      user
      displayName: snapshot.val()
    }));
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a syntax problem. Arrow functions have a few valid configurations with brackets etc.  that can be tough to sort out (it still bites me sometimes after a year of using ES6).

Here's a few valid versions to consider. This isn't an exhaustive list of possible syntax combinations, but I find it covers most of my use cases:

Standard form,  multi line block, brackets. This is the version you use when you have more to do than just return a value (e.g., side effects like `dispatch`):

```
(snapshot) => { 
    const displayname = snapshot. val()
    // then you'd dispatch here
     return
 }
```

One liner, term after the arrow is assumed to be return value. No assignments on the right side in this version, and no `dispatch` calls:

```
  snapshot => snapshot.val()
```

In-between, multiple lines enclosed by parentheses, but still just one value assumed to be return value:

```
snapshot => ({
      displayName:  snapshot.val()
    }) 
  // returns { displayName: "foo"  }
```